# If we replace the faces of a dodecahedron, do we still get a regular polyhedron?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, polyhedra

I've been reading old works by Coxeter, thinking foundationally about his ideas concerning the Wythoff construction and the abstract definition of regularity as a polyhedron whose symmetry group acts transitively on the set of flags.

The other day, when attempting to use these ideas I realised the existence of star polygons (by no means an original thought) and noticed they were regular. I then realised there were apparently regular star polyhedra listed but my question is this:

**What about the shape (polyhedron?) formed when you replace each face of a dodecahedron by a pentagram?**

This appears to be regular, by the definition of transitivity of symmetry group acting on flags, but is not listed. Is this not a polyhedron? I understand it is not convex, but neither are the Kepler-Poinsot solids...

Answer (score 5):

If you keep the pentagrams inscribed in the original pentagonal faces, then this is not any kind of polyhedron, since the faces do not connect to each other: every edge lies only on a single face.

If you scale up the pentagrams such that these edges *do* meet, then you can obtain two different Kepler-Poinsot solids depending on the scaling factor: the [small stellated dodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_stellated_dodecahedron) and the [great stellated dodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_stellated_dodecahedron).

Comment: Where in the definition of polyhedron does it forbid an edge lying on a single face? Is that some kind of requirement? Why?

Comment: There are many definitions of polyhedra, and most authors neglect to give *any* precisely specified formulation. But of the ones that do, it is near-universally the case that edges are shared by exactly two faces. See [George Hart's glossary](http://www.georgehart.com/virtual-polyhedra/glossary.html) for one example: A three-dimensional object bounded by polygons, *with each edge shared by exactly two polygons*.

Comment: Is there some reason for this? What kinds of things arise if you allow, say, 3 polygons? How does this definition generalise.

Also, this definition you mention seems somewhat deficient: for example, in what sense do the Kepler-Poinsot solids actually "bound" anything? Their "faces" are simply pentagrams and the traditional opaqueness drawn in seems to be no more than a convention.

Comment: I mean maybe my comment has no good answer, I have realised, as it's not really very formal. If you have anything more to share though about why this definition might be the correct one, I'd really like to hear it. What is the definition in nD?

Comment: An example of something very "non-polyhedral" that can show up with three polygons at an edge is a triangle with cubes attached at edge, free to swing this way and that. In general having more than two faces at an edge means that you can't coherently talk about an "inside" and an "outside" of the polyhedron, even locally - it breaks things topologically.

Comment: The Kepler-Poinsot solids are weird, and indeed not considered polyhedra by many people - if someone asked a question about "polyhedra" without further elaboration, I would assume they were excluding the possibility of self-intersection. But the Kepler-Poinsot solids do behave fairly well outside the vertices, and you can imagine "smoothing out" their edges to form a surface outside of the singularities at the vertices which plays nicely on a local level. Someone better-versed in these things might have more formal remarks to make here; I don't think a lot about self-intersecting polyhedra.

Comment: In $n$ dimensions, I think the analogous necessarily condition (I don't know whether it'd be sufficient, my experience with higher-dimensional nonstandard polyhedra is even less) would be that each $(n-2)$-cell should lie on exactly two $(n-1)$-cells, and of course that all the cells are themselves valid polytopes of the corresponding dimension. So in the 2D case this is just saying that all vertices have degree $2$.